# Subquerying results in no row returned although records exist

Tags: subquery

I have two tables, namely Employees and Payments. Below is the contents of the two:

The Employees table

```
 EmpID |EmpName
 ------ --------
   113    Harry
```

The Payments table

```
EmpID | Amount | Period | PaymentType | St
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------     
113 |  100   | 201207 |    1        |  1
------------------------------------------
113 |  70    | 201206 |    1        |  0
------------------------------------------
113 |  120   | 201207 |    1        |  0
------------------------------------------
113 |  200   | 201207 |    1        |  1
------------------------------------------
113 |  90    | 201207 |    2        |  1
------------------------------------------
```

Here's my query:

```
    SELECT EMP.EMPID ID, PAID_TOTAL,PAID_CURRENT,PAID_PAST,PAID_OT
  FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
  , (
      SELECT EMPID,SUM(AMOUNT)PAID_TOTAL
      FROM PAYMENTS
      WHERE PERIOD<='201207' AND ST=1
      GROUP BY EMPID
    )
    PY_TOTAL, (
      SELECT EMPID,SUM(AMOUNT)PAID_CURRENT
      FROM PAYMENTS
      WHERE PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=1 AND ST=1
      GROUP BY EMPID
    )
    PY_CURRENT, (
      SELECT EMPID,SUM(AMOUNT)PAID_PAST
      FROM PAYMENTS
      WHERE PERIOD<'201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=1 AND ST=1
      GROUP BY EMPID
    )
    PY_PAST, (
      SELECT EMPID,SUM(AMOUNT)PAID_OT
      FROM PAYMENTS
      WHERE PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=2 AND ST=1
      GROUP BY EMPID
    )
    PY_OT
  WHERE 
    (
      EMP.EMPID=PY_TOTAL.EMPID OR EMP.EMPID=PY_CURRENT.EMPID OR
      EMP.EMPID=PY_PAST.EMPID OR EMP.EMPID=PY_OT.EMPID
    );
```

What I would expect to get is:

```
  ID | PAID_TOTAL | PAID_CURRENT | PAID_PAST | PAID_OT
  113     460          300             70         90
```

But no row is returned from the above query.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Period`, is it datetime? That would explain one of the derived tables to have no rows in the result - and thus the whole query as well. Try running each derived table individually.

Comment: And those `OR` should be `AND` (and then converted to explicit `JOIN`s).

Comment: The DataType of the Period column is Varchar2. You're right, I've in fact made a change to my Payments table content. With the previous data the query in fact would return the expected result. But when one of the derived tables returns no rows, then the whole query comes up with no result. I wonder why. The problem is, even if I omit the where part in the above query, I get nothing.

Comment: Because you then have a cross join of 5 tables. If one of them has 0 rows, the final outcome will have `200 x 1200 x 645 x 0 x 179`. Multiplication by 0 has this nice effect. Convert the query to use `LEFT JOIN` instead. Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Or convert to have a subquery returning a single value or NULL at each *column* position.

Comment: Hmmmm. I see. I'm in Oracle. How am I supposed to use LEFT JOIN? If I do so, I'll get result anyways because there is one in the Employees table. An alternative to my query will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the subqueries (derived tables) returns 0 rows and thus the whole query - which is a cross join of 5 tables - returns 0 rows as well.

You could rewrite with proper, explicit joins. If you make them outer (`LEFT`) joins, then you'll get results if one of the subqueries has 0 rows:

```
  SELECT EMP.EMPID ID, 
         COALESCE(PAID_TOTAL, 0) AS PAID_TOTAL,
         COALESCE(PAID_CURRENT, 0) AS PAID_CURRENT,
         COALESCE(PAID_PAST, 0) AS PAID_PAST,
         COALESCE(PAID_OT, 0) AS PAID_OT
  FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT EMPID,SUM(AMOUNT)PAID_TOTAL
      FROM PAYMENTS
      WHERE PERIOD<='201207' AND ST=1
      GROUP BY EMPID
      ) PY_TOTAL ON EMP.EMPID=PY_TOTAL.EMPID
    ---
    --- more LEFT joins
    ---
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT EMPID,SUM(AMOUNT)PAID_OT
      FROM PAYMENTS
      WHERE PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=2 AND ST=1
      GROUP BY EMPID
    ) PY_OT ON EMP.EMPID=PY_OT.EMPID ;
```

---

But it could be written even simpler, with only one join to `Payments` table:

```
  SELECT 
      EMP.EMPID AS ID, 
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN PERIOD<='201207' AND ST=1 THEN AMOUNT END), 0)
          AS PAID_TOTAL,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=1 AND ST=1 THEN AMOUNT END), 0)
          AS PAID_CURRENT,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN PERIOD<'201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=1 AND ST=1 THEN AMOUNT END), 0)
          AS PAID_PAST,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=2 AND ST=1 THEN AMOUNT END), 0)
          AS PAID_OT
  FROM EMPLOYEES  EMP
    LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS  P
      ON EMP.EMPID = P.EMPID
  GROUP BY EMP.EMPID ;
```

This may not be as efficient or need different indexes but it can easily be changed to include in the results only employees with at least one payment:

```
  FROM EMPLOYEES  EMP
    INNER JOIN PAYMENTS  P
      ON EMP.EMPID = P.EMPID
```

or employees with at least one payment in the examined period/restrictions:

```
  FROM EMPLOYEES  EMP
    INNER JOIN PAYMENTS  P
      ON  EMP.EMPID = P.EMPID
      AND (P.PERIOD<='201207' AND P.ST=1)
```

The `(P.PERIOD<='201207' AND P.ST=1)` condition is the `OR` of all the 4 conditions, simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in the comment above, an alternative answer would be to put the subqueries in the select clause, as follows:

```
SELECT
  EMPID AS ID, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM PAYMENTS
    WHERE PERIOD<='201207' AND ST=1
    AND EMPID = EMP.EMPID
  ) AS PAID_TOTAL,
  (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM PAYMENTS
    WHERE PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=1 AND ST=1
    AND EMPID = EMP.EMPID
  ) AS PAID_CURRENT,
  (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM PAYMENTS
    WHERE PERIOD<'201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=1 AND ST=1
    AND EMPID = EMP.EMPID
  ) AS PAID_PAST,
  (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM PAYMENTS
    WHERE PERIOD='201207' AND PAYMENTTYPE=2 AND ST=1
    AND EMPID = EMP.EMPID
  ) AS PAID_OT
FROM EMPLOYEES EMP;
```

I often prefer this approach as it avoids GROUP BY, any explicit (OUTER) JOINs and COALESCE.

Comment: The problem with your variant is it returns even those rows where only Employees table has rows and the Payments table has no corresponding row.

Comment: Right, but then you could either
a) add COALESCE/NVL and return 0;
b) filter out employees without payments with an ordinary JOIN to payments; or
c) just add `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PAYMENTS WHERE EMPID = EMP.EMPID)`.